# How to remove default axis and creating new custom axis in Amcharts5 Line Chart?

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts5

I need to create a line series chart with value axis as x axis.Hence i need to disable the default axis generated and create my own custom axis where i can specify the interval distance.

[Actual Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rriV.png)

[Expected Axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09B13.png)

i have tried keeping x axis

```
    renderer.grid.template.set('visible', false);
```

and putting condition to display only range values present in chart data.

```
       xAxis.get('renderer').labels.template.adapters.add('text', (text) => {
            const allowedRange = this.series.values.data.map((x) => x.range.toString());
            if (allowedRange.includes(text)) {
                return text;
            }
        });
```

This solves the issues , but the grid lines are not matching with axis intervals.
Is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do, but I think you should use the `minGridDistance` property on your `xAxis` renderer. Take a look at the documentation: [IAxisRendererSettings – amCharts 5 Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/iaxisrenderersettings/#minGridDistance_property)

Here is an example:

```js
am5.ready(() => {

  let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  let chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));

  let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
      minGridDistance: 30 // Play with it and see what happens...
    })
  }));

  let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));

  let series = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueXField: "valueX",
    valueYField: "valueY"
  }));
  
  let data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    data.push({ valueX: i, valueY: i });
  }

  series.data.setAll(data);

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want a custom interval, you have to disable the default grid and labels. Then you can use axis ranges to get the desired result. There is an official tutorial here: [Using axis ranges to place labels at arbitrary values or dates – amCharts 5 Documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/tutorials/using-axis-ranges-to-place-labels-at-arbitrary-values-or-dates/)

I updated my example:

```js
am5.ready(() => {

  let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

  let chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {}));

  let xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    min: 0,
    max: 120,
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {})
  }));
  
  let xRenderer = xAxis.get("renderer");
  
  xRenderer.grid.template.set("forceHidden", true);
  xRenderer.labels.template.set("forceHidden", true);
  
  function createRange(value) {
    let rangeDataItem = xAxis.makeDataItem({ value }),
        range = xAxis.createAxisRange(rangeDataItem);

    range.get("grid").setAll({
      forceHidden: false,
      strokeOpacity: 0.2,
      location: 1
    });
    
    range.get("label").setAll({
      forceHidden: false,
      text: `${value}`
    });
  }

  createRange(0);
  createRange(30);
  createRange(60);
  createRange(90);
  createRange(120);

  let yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));

  let series = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueXField: "valueX",
    valueYField: "valueY"
  }));
  
  let data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
    data.push({ valueX: i, valueY: i });
  }

  series.data.setAll(data);

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: I tried changing the minGridDistance , but didn't get the desired interval  
0-30 , 30-60 ..., is there any way to specify the interval.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should be OK this time.